# Error in Six Sigma Rolled Throughput Yield Calculation

Tags: statistics

I've been looking at running some calculations on process yields and landed on Rolled Throughput Yield and Six Sigma.

I had been using the product of all process yields in the past, no idea Six Sigma used this.  The reason I went searching is that this approach produces the wrong result in any process that counts output in integers rather than real numbers.

In other words, if I am making jogging pants, I can't make 23.451 jogging pants. I make 23.  Here's an example:

```
Number of steps:            20  
Yield per process:          89.3%   
Rolled Throughput Yield:    10.4%   

Starting assemblies:                                100 
Number of good assemblies according to RTY:          10 
Number of good assemblies calculated sequentially:    6 

            yield       sequentially    
step 1      89.3%       89.0    
step 2      89.3%       79.0    
step 3      89.3%       70.0    
step 4      89.3%       62.0    
step 5      89.3%       55.0    
step 6      89.3%       49.0    
step 7      89.3%       43.0    
step 8      89.3%       38.0    
step 9      89.3%       33.0    
step 10     89.3%       29.0    
step 11     89.3%       25.0    
step 12     89.3%       22.0    
step 13     89.3%       19.0    
step 14     89.3%       16.0    
step 15     89.3%       14.0    
step 16     89.3%       12.0    
step 17     89.3%       10.0    
step 18     89.3%        8.0    
step 19     89.3%        7.0    
step 20     89.3%        6.0
```

Two part question:

a) Why does anyone use the product-of-yields approach when it isn't accurate?

b) Is there a mathematical expression that can take a set of process yields (all different, not like the example above) and produce a result equivalent to rounding down the prior calculation's result so you don't end-up counting 1/10 th. of a pant ten times?

I think the answer to (b) is "no".  My guess is this has to be done in code or via a series of formulas in Excel (which is exactly how I created the example above).

Comment: There are two "mistakes" with your analysis: First, your result depends on the initial sample size. You start with 100 samples, which is why you "floor" the number in every step. If you would start with 100,000 samples the result is much closer to (89.3%)^20. Second, you omit that the 89.3% are the average value of a **distribution**. In each step you have to sample from this distribution, instead of taking only the average value. Taking only the average is only fine if you start with a large sample  -- as mentioned in the first "mistake".